# Why are browsers not standardized for HTML/CSS

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

It seems like everyone takes for granted that browsers are just different from each other. It makes programming very redundant, like this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
```

This seems really stupid and I have no idea why these browsers are making development so hard. Why are they different from each other? Is there any objective reason?

And it's not just CSS. JS also performs differently depending on the browser. such as detecting what key the user presses.

Comment: why doesn't all the human talk only one unique language? it would make our life easier and we avoid a lot of headaches with translation and learning foreign language.

Comment: Uhh I don't think I'm getting your analogy

Comment: This is embrace, extend, extinguish. Eventually one browser will win the competition, and then they will decide how the web works with only them. This is happening right now with Chromium. The end goal is becoming clear. Some websites, and more and more of them will only work with Chromium. Right now I'm trying to use CircuitLab, which has just taken my work hostage to signing up. I signed up with firefox android, and now it complains my browser "does not meet the requirements". Welcome to the future of the web.

Answer (score -1):

Each of these venfor-prefixed properties (Chrome has -webkit, -o is Opera etc..) are used for proprietary or new CSS features, as they're not yet confirmed.

They should  be removed with time, when the property is finally implemented in a browser.

Comment: yeah but its not just vendor prefixes, what about getting what key the user presses? Some browsers use event.which and some use event.keyCode